# Web Worker overhead metrics

Tags: javascript, multithreading, browser, web-worker, overhead

I'm working on a project that may require multiple web workers and I need to know whether it's affordable to have multiple operating at the same time (as in more than 4 or 8 workers) and what the cost is in both cpu and ram to start them up and have them lingering.

I've been googling and searching but I haven't found any metrics on their cpu and memory overhead. I've found some benchmarks for performance, but that's not what I'm interested in.

Can anyone point me to either a spec or study that gives at least approximate values? I need to at least have some ballpark values to work with, rather than just assume whatever I see from Process Explorer is accurate or reliable.

**edit - It seems people are getting the wrong impression. I'm *not* asking for advice on how to solve a problem but sources of technical information on web worker overhead, if they exist.**

Comment: Why do you try it and see?

Comment: @bhspencer I have, but that doesn't feel accurate to do with test scripts and I need to know before I end up designing a system based on either lots of workers (thus simple) or few (more complicated) and then having to refactor the entire thing. If there's info, that would help me save a lot of time.

Comment: Any overhead is going to be relative to the amount work you plan to do with the worker. i.e. if you are only doing a small amount of computation in the worker the relative overhead will be high. As such I don't think you can quantify overhead in a general way very easily. The overhead to work ratio is going to be specific to your project.

Comment: @bhspencer Yes but does that include the startup/idling overhead or memory usage? It's possible for the overheads of everything, except whatever processing is handled, to be comparable in size and thus indistinguishable, yet dependent on parameters I'm missing. All I'm asking is if there's some spec or study someone has made to put more concrete numbers to these. If such a thing doesn't exist, then that's an answer. I just don't see how nothing can be said about such overheads, when in other cases, people mention it as a point to be taken into account when spawning multiple workers.

Comment: One thing to consider is that if this is running in a browser you may not know the specifications of the machine it is going to be running on. 8 concurrent threads performing computation is only going to be of benefit if the system running the code can run 8 threads simultaneously. A 2 core machine without hyper threading is not going to benefit from 8 threads of computation.

Comment: @bhspencer I'm not using threads for performance gains, so that's fine. The purpose is primarily to separate code, which is why I'm interested primarily in memory costs and cpu/memory overheads.

Comment: Encapsulation of code can be achieved in much simpler ways that spawning worker threads. I suggest doing yourself a favor and keep it all single threaded.

Comment: @bhspencer It's not for encapsulation alone, it's about sandboxing plugin code. Hopefully this makes it more clear why I need to know - is it ok to spawn a worker per plugin or should I try to put all of them in one? Or split them between a few? Without some a priori information, all I'm left with is implementing both and using real-life examples to test them after the fact. Why is it so bad to try and see if there's information already available on this?

Comment: Without understanding more about what you're doing with the code that runs in the webWorkers, we can't really say whether you should be using zero webWorkers, one webWorker per plug-in or something in between.  The usual way of doing things in JS is to run multiple tasks in a single thread by using async I/O without using a thread per task.  Plus many/most browsers will not have 8 actual CPU cores so you're not actually getting full simultaneous execution in that case.

Comment: @jfriend00 The question isn't specific to my work, it's more general than that. I'm not asking for advice but whether there is specific technical information available. As I've said in the above comments, concurrency and performance are not my concern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Workers API spawns real OS threads, so a lot of that performance bottleneck might not even be at the browser level.

Understandably, you still want metrics to see how much overhead a browser adds. You're either on your own if you want objective results.

Some blog posts might give you a good starting point: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/how-fast-are-web-workers/

(EDIT: actually keep reading the link, and you'll find he has open-sourced the metric tooling used for the blog post: https://github.com/gmarty/web-workers-benchmark)

Comment: Thanks for the link. My question was primarily about cpu and memory overhead though - the blog post and app measure latency and creation time (and some filenames need correcting in the app - and probably firefox OS to run it, has some api calls that aren't supported in FF46.0a2). Regardless this answer is the closest so far so you get my upvote and I'll accept this one unless a better one comes along. It seems like I'll have to do it manually and try to avoid mistakes in my measurements.

Comment: 3 years later, I went to this answer, and I really appreciate that the question has been posted and an interesting link provided. Having a few workers to manage (less than 10), but large objects to message (around 1M each), it helped me to design an efficient split mechanism for parallelizing the processing.